# htaccess redirect whilst parsing query string and variable

Tags: .htaccess, query-string, redirect

How do you redirect a subdomain whilst capturing anything after the '?' and appending to a redirect using htaccess, whilst maintaining a particular variable?

redirect from...

```
http://subdomain1.example.com/?retailcentre=subdomain1&utm_source=twitter&utm_medium=twitter&utm_campaign=022641example
```

to...

```
http://www.example.com/?retailcentre=subdomain1&utm_source=twitter&utm_medium=twitter&utm_campaign=022641example
```

The query string after the '?' could be anything as it could come from twitter, facebook etc.

The one var that has to be parsed is what subdomain the redirect came from, in this case 'retailcentre'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain1\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI}?retailcentre=subdomain1 [QSA,NE,R=301,L]
```

`[QSA]` Flag:  When the replacement URI contains a query string, the default behavior of RewriteRule is to discard the existing query string, and replace it with the newly generated one. Using the [QSA] flag causes the query strings to be combined.

Comment: Thanks, this is close but is missing the 'retailcentre' variable. The value for this variable is taken from the subdomain part of the URL, so the '?retailcentre=subdomain1' part is followed by the query string in the original URL. is this possible?

Comment: I nearly got this to work, i've used the following...

`RewriteRule ^ http://www.example.com/?retailcentre=subdomain1$1%{REQUEST_URI} [QSA,NE,R=301,L]` ... but it adds a `%2F` after the value of 'retailcentre'.

Comment: So my reditected URL looks like this `http://www.example.com/?retailcentre=subdomain1%2F&utm_source=email&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=022641ReservedEventCustomerEmail`. I want to remove the `%2F`

Comment: Retailcentre is in your "redirect from" exemple... I edit my code with that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following rules :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com$
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /\?retailcentre=.+&utm_source=.+&utm_medium=.+&utm_campaign=.+\sHTTP [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://example.com/ [L,R,NE]
```

Comment: This won't work in this scenario because I have to capture anything that comes after the '?' and not specific variables as you have.